# To find object whereabouts in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var result = [];
  var arr1 = Object.keys(source);
  console.log(arr1);

  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
      if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(arr1[j]) === false) { //Check 1 if false go to next object  in collection
        break;
      } else if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(arr1[j])) {
        console.log(source[arr1[j]], collection[i][arr1[j]])
        if (source[arr1[j]] !== collection[i][arr1[j]]) { //Check 2 if value is not equal break loop and goto next object in collection
          break;
        }
        continue; // if both check passes go for  next  property of source to check in object;
      }
      result.push(collection[i]); //if all values are present and checked in object push it in result array.
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(whatIsInAName(
  [
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }
  ], {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
));
```

I couldn't figure out the problem in my logic. I try to debug it even but can't find what the hell is a problem with logic.The program is to make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching property and value pairs (second argument) Kindly help me over, please.

```
whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 })
```

should return

```
[{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }].
```

and

```
whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2 }], { "a": 1 })
```

should return

```
[{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2 }].
```

Comment: please add some samples. according to inputs, which outputs are expected?

Comment: Your issue is simple and no one will tell you straight up. You are hitting your `continue` and it's forcing your loop to skip your `result.push` statement. 

You can simply make your code read `else if{ j < arr1.length - 1){ continue}` and it will work.

This will make it so that you know it has made it through the last iteration and it didn't fail the break test so it needs to pass. Skipping `continue` but making sure to hit the `result.push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem with your code :**

What you are doing currently is that if all the if statements pass, and loops do not break anywhere, you put continue again at the last item of arr1. So, it goes to check next iteration, does not find it, and goes to next iteration in the collection loop. While doing this, it does not push any item to result.

**Solution:**

In your code: You should use continue like this.

```
if(j !==(arr1.length - 1)) 
  continue;
```

This gives your code an opportunity to push item to result array.

Comment: Ok I get ur point but whats the problem in my code. I dont wanna use built-in methods. I am checking all logics and passing every test that should be done. I debug the code and logics seem fine too but why its not pushing the object that passes test to result array .....I just wanna know the logic error in my code

Comment: @bidaxi check my updated answer for problem in your code.

Comment: bro I love u man seriously u did it. I approach many platforms no one was giving me solution instead giving me other ideas to solve the problem <3 stay blessed. Hope u get all the success. It works. thats what I want the exact reason my code was not working....

Answer (score 1):

Well you are complicating it too much with these two for loops, you can do it better using `Array` built-in methods.

This is  how you can do it using **[`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** methods:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {

    var result = [];
    var arr1 = Object.keys(source);
    console.log(arr1);

    result = collection.filter(function(obj){
          return !arr1.some(function(k){
              return !obj[k] || obj[k] !== source[k];
          });
    });
    return result;
    }

    console.log(whatIsInAName([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }], { a: 1, b: 2 }));
```

Comment: `.every()` is simpler here, rather than double negating your logic. It also removes the `obj[k]` check, because you would be checking for equality, rather than inequality.

Comment: Ok I get ur point but whats the problem in my code. I dont wanna use built-in methods. I am checking all logics and passing every test that should be done. I debug the code and logics seem fine too but why its not pushing the object that passes test to result array .....I just wanna know the logic error in my code

Comment: @bidaxi your problem is that you are coplicating things with too much `loops` and too much `if` chacks, which made you use an extra `continue`statement in your last `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating things. A simple `.filter()` will do. Inside that `.filter()` you can check to see if *every* value for every key in `source` matches with the corresponding key in `collection` by using the handy, built-in `.every()` method.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var sourceKeys = Object.keys(source);
  return collection.filter(function (coll) {
    // if you want to return only exact matches, just add the test to make sure same # of keys, and all keys match w/ values.
    // (Object.keys(coll).length === sourceKeys.length) && sourceKeys.every(...)
    return sourceKeys.every(function (key) {
      return coll[key] === source[key];
    });
  });
}

console.log(whatIsInAName(
  [
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }
  ], {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
));
```

Alternatively, with ES6 Syntax:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  return collection.filter(coll => Object.keys(source).every(key => coll[key] === source[key]));
}

console.log(whatIsInAName(
  [
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }
  ], {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
));
```

Comment: Ok I get ur point but whats the problem in my code. I dont wanna use built-in methods. I am checking all logics and passing every test that should be done. I debug the code and logics seem fine too but why its not pushing the object that passes test  to result array .....I just wanna know the error in my code

Comment: @bidaxi If you don't want to use built-in methods, better get rid of `Array.push()`, `Object.keys()`, and `Object.hasOwnProperty()`.. just saying.. They are built-in for a reason. The issue with your code is you have over-complicated it. Period. Tracking down the exact error when you can rewrite it as a 3 line solution is a waste of time, and passing that code on to someone else who maintains your code in the future would be a crime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function whatIsInAName(arr, sources){
  return arr.filter((item) => {
    for(source in sources){
        if(!item[source] || item[source] !== sources[source]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  })    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are hitting your continue instead of falling out of the loop. I updated your code here:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var result = [];
    var arr1 = Object.keys(source);
    console.log(arr1);

    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            if (!collection[i].hasOwnProperty(arr1[j])) { //Check 1 if false go to next object  in collection
                break;
            } else if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(arr1[j])) {
                console.log(source[arr1[j]], collection[i][arr1[j]])
                if (source[arr1[j]] !== collection[i][arr1[j]]) { //Check 2 if value is not equal break loop and goto next object in collection
                  break;
                }else if(j < arr1.length - 1){
                    continue; // if both check passes go for  next  property of source to check in object;
                }

            }
            result.push(collection[i]); 
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(whatIsInAName(
  [
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }
  ], 
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
)); // result is [Object {...}, Object {...}] which objects are {a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}
```